$A+B$ closed if $A$ and $B$ are closed
Let $A,B$ be subset of $\mathbb R^n$, both closed.
I want to prove that $A+B$ is closed too.
I know how to prove with one of both sets is compact but not without.
Please help me, i struggle finding a solution.
This question is a duplicate, please dont answer no more.

False even in $\mathbb R$  and this has been answered  many times.

A counterexample is $A=\mathbb Z$ and $B$ the set of positive rational numbers $p/q$  in reduced form, with $p>q^2.$ Then $A+B$ is all the rational numbers.

$A=\mathbb Z, B=\sqrt 2 \mathbb Z$ is a standard example.

Thank you should i delete my question now @geetha290krm

I was dumb sorry

@DimitryPetruschka Don't kick yourself. Asking questions is a big part of how we learn.

Hello new User! Please youse Mathjax, when typing down your questions to increase e.g. readability!
Here is a link for a Tutorial:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Oh thank you @ThomasAndrews

Define $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ by $A=\{(0,x)\mid x\leq -1\}$ and $B=\{(x,\frac{1}{x})\mid 0<x\leq 1\}$. Then $A,B$ are closed and $(0,0)\notin A+B$ but $(0,0)$ is in the closure of $A+B$ since $(x,0)\in A+B$ for all $0<x\leq 1$.

Please avoid answering duplicates.

Oh thank you, i see.

@geetha290krm While it is true people shouldn't answer duplicate questions, until you find a duplicate, people don't know.
